# My mac is not booting

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

I was on my macbook today, and suddenly a flashing file with a questions mark appeared, and now i cant start my mac. It says ( support.apple.com/mac/startup) . I've tried diferrent ways, first aid the drive, but i got an error (something that is failing ), i've tried to reinstall the macos but it says " disk locked" . What can i do, really need what i have on the mac..

Note: dont want to erase may data from the mac .

Comment: What exact model of MacBook is this? (Year, size, Air/Pro...?) Do you not have a backup of your data? Do you have an external USB disk that you could instal MacOs onto, and then boot from there?

Comment: Can you boot in Recovery mode (cmd+r at boot) then chose Utility at the top menu and Terminal and give the result of command ``diskutil list``

Comment: @Jean_JD i already did that, but how can this help me ?

Comment: @benwiggy macbook pro 13 2017, i dont have a back up of my data.

Comment: From the Recovery mode you can open two terminal (cmd+n) then in the second you can open a Safari windows : ``/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`` then you can copy here and give the results of the command ``diskutil list`` (from the other terminal).